# Pagination not working with wice_grid Gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, wice-grid

I am working on Rails project and I am using "wice_grid" gem to create grids.
It is throwing an error when I try to paginate the results:

```
undefined method `num_pages' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f43b89a1610>
```

and here is my code:

**In Controller**

```
    def index
        @root_url="http://"+"#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}";
        @users_grid = initialize_grid(User,:per_page => 20, :conditions => ['role= ?', "user"], :order => 'created_at',:order_direction => 'desc')
        @count=User.where(:role=>"user").count
        @record_per_page=20
        @total_record=@count/@record_per_page.ceil
    end
```

**In View**

```
<div class="widget-content" >
    <%= grid(@users_grid,:html=>{:class=>'table table-striped table-bordered',:id=>"tbl1"}) do |g| %>

        <% g.column  :name => 'FIRST NAME', :attribute => 'first_name',:html=>{:id=>"firstname"} do |user| %>
            <% content_tag(:td,:name => 'FIRST NAME', :attribute => 'first_name',onclick:"show(#{user.id});",:style=>"cursor:pointer") do %>
                <% user.first_name %>
           <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <% g.column  :name => 'LAST NAME', :attribute => 'last_name',:html=>{:id=>"lastname"} do |user| %>
           <% content_tag(:td,:name => 'LAST NAME', :attribute => 'last_name',onclick:"show(#{user.id});",:style=>"cursor:pointer") do %>
                <% user.last_name %>
           <% end %>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

I have tried my best to fix this, but all in vain.

Comment: Do you use `will_paginate` for pagination?

Comment: @yzalavin yes i do

Comment: Check https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/issues/280

Comment: okay it worked if i use 
"@users_grid = initialize_grid(User.where(role: "user"))"
instead of 
"@users_grid = initialize_grid(User, :per_page => 20, :conditions => ['role= ?', "user"])"
in controller

but i have to use the second one, what's wrong with the second one?

Comment: The first case does not apply pagination. The second one does. `wice_grid` uses `kaminari` for pagination. `kaminari` conflicts with `will_paginate`. You can either replace `will_paginate` with `kaminari` or monkey patch like [here](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/issues/280)

Comment: what if i remove will_paginate gem??

Comment: i tried removing it, still not works, if it conflicts with kaminari then after removing will_paginate it should work, right? why it still not works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147071/discussion-between-insomania-and-yzalavin).